# Cannot see the dev tools with nw.js

Tags: nw.js

I just downloaded nw.js normal v0.19.3 and I see that the manifest option "toolbar" is no longer supported. It says that F12 should bring up the dev tools but it's not working. I'm using a mackbook BUT I'm booted into Win 8. Any idea on how I can see the dev tools?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download SDK version of NWJS instead of Normal version, as Normal version doesn't have dev tools

After downloading SDK version

```
1. Start App
2. Right click on App, you will see two options inspect (which will open dev tool for foreground page), inspect background page (which will open dev tool for background page)
3. Or Press Cmd + Option + i, to open dev tools for foreground page
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/70 and https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/5120